# Spring Security - Users redirect based on business logic post successful authentication for all secure pages/views

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Newbie Spring MVC/Security question. I have managed to implement Spring Security to manage user security/authentication. I would now like to implement business logic for authenticated users with redirects to different views/pages based on the result of the business logic.

For example (assuming user has successfully passed authentication and has the required Role for requested view/page):

- IF user hasn’t validated their email yet > display email validation
  error view/page with link to resend email validation email
- ELSE IF user fails some other business logic > display page X
- ELSE IF user fails some other business logic > display page Y
- ELSE > display
  default post-authentication view/page OR requested view/page

I’ve searched around and found possible ways of implementing this (e.g. custom authenticationSuccessHandler and Filtering) but of the examples I have found I’m unsure:

a)  How to redirect to different views/pages based on the result of the business logic

b)  Whether the approach will handle users that try and access pages directly (i.e. users that pass authentication that haven’t validated their email should be redirected to “email validation error” view/page no matter what they are trying to access – even when they try and access a (secure) view/page directly)

An alternative to the above is to include business logic within every controller but this doesn’t feel right and am sure there must be a more elegant way of handling this requirement

Anyways I’m keen to understand the “best/standard” approach (if such a thing exists!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at this as a [cross cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), so in my opinion you're right to be considering the filtering approach. I don't think implementing a [custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) is the right way to do it. By using a filter, you will gain control over which URLs the logic applies too, not only when the user authenticates.

As to how you achieve the filtering, there are a couple of ways to configure it, but I can't see you needing to do anything more complicated than provide a well tested javax.servlet.Filter implementation.

Option 1 would be to configure your Servlet Filter as part of the Spring Security filter chain. Spring Security is implemented as a series of Filters, each with a clearly defined role. Spring Security allows you to insert custom filters into this chain for application-specific security related logic. The Spring Security documentation discusses this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters).

You've said that before hitting your business logic, you expect the user to have authenticated and their role to have been checked, so you could insert your filter towards the rear of the Spring Security filter chain, relying on the Spring Security Filter implementations to enforce authentication and role checking.

An alternative would be to configure you Filter implementation directly in your web.xml, ensuring that it is only invoked on URLs that are protected by Spring Security. Here the order of declaring your filters in web.xml would become important as you would need to ensure that the Spring Security Filter chain was invoked first (to ensure the user is authenticated and has the correct role) before your custom Filter is invoked.

Comment: Filter seems like the obvious choice but am still confused on how this could be used to redirect user to a different page/screen.depending on the outcome of the business logic within it

Comment: Thats great. I got it working by a combination of the two:

Post Success Handler to set a session variable (e.g. emailValidated = true/flase

Filter to check that session variable emailValidated = true and redirecting user to validate your email page if it = false

The emailvalidation controller is also responsible for changing the state of emailValidated in session for users that validate their email (by clicking on a link)